# Validate two properties are equal

Tags: javascript, joi

Is it possible to validate that two object properties of type `string` are equal using `Joi`?

I found `Joi.ref()` but I wonder if there's another way of doing it. Especially as `Joi.ref()` doesn't seem to support `any.error()`

Comment: I remember you, you created the npm package `docker-compose`, thanks for that! 
Could you describe in detail what do you try to do with `any.error()`? Should a password match the other one and which error messages do you want?

Comment: Password match is excactly the intented use case here. How it is done using `Joi` doesn't matter. I just want to use `Joi` when possible.

Comment: I found a solution that works with `Joi.ref()`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to check if two properties on a object are the same. And using `Joi.ref()` is the preferred way to do it.

If you want to use **custom error messages** the [`Joi.any.messages()`](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.5#anymessagesmessages) option works the best. The `Joi.any.messages()` lets you overwrite the different error messages that a property is producing.

You could also use the [`Joi.any.error()`](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.5#anyerrorerr) option but that is not that elegant and you would need to [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) between the different error codes (like `string.base`, `any.required`, `any.only`...)

#### Complete Solution using `Joi.any.messages()`

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  first: Joi.string().required(),
  second: Joi.string().required().equal(Joi.ref('first'))
          .messages({
            'string.base': 'second is not a string', // typeof second !== 'string || second === null
            'any.required': 'second is required', // undefined
            'any.only': 'second must match first' // second !== first
          })
});

const value = {
  first: 'hello',
  second: 'hello',
};

const result = schema.validate(value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.error, null, 2));
```