# Returning multiple errors in Joi

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to return multiple custom error messages from my Joi validation schema. Here is the schema

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");
const string = Joi.string();
const emailSchema = string.email();
const usernameSchema = string
  .min(3)
  .max(30)
  .error(() => "Username must be between 3 and 30 characters");
const passwordSchema = string
  .min(6)
  .error(() => "Password must be at least 6 characters");
const confirmPasswordSchema = Joi.valid(Joi.ref("passwordSchema")).error(
  () => "Passwords must match"
);

const localRegistrationSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  email: emailSchema.required().error(() => "Email is required"),
  username: usernameSchema.required().error(() => "Username is required"),
  password: passwordSchema.required().error(() => "Password is required"),
  confirmPassword: confirmPasswordSchema
});
```

and here is where I am using the schema

```
const { error } = localRegistrationSchema.validate(req.body, {
        abortEarly: false
      });
console.log(error);
if (error) throw Boom.boomify(error);
```

But I keep getting an TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined which looks to be caused by

```
details.push({
    message,
    path: item.path.filter((v) => typeof v !== 'object'),
    type: item.code,
    context: item.local
});
```

which is part of Joi's error handling code

I do not get this error when I don't attach the .error() part but I cannot get more than one error to show if I use .error(new Error("custom error message")

I can't figure out what is going wrong and I haven't been able to get any other way of returning multiple custom error messages to work

Comment: Joel Jacobson I found a more elegant solution. You can use the `Joi.any.messages()` option. For a complete example see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198097/5536304

Comment: Thank you!! That works fantastic. However, I did find one caveat that also affects the original code you gave as well as the code in the example you linked. When you do string().required() it throws a string.empty error rather than an any.required error, so checking any.required does not work. You have to check string.empty. I do not know if it is the same for other types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seening that this is still getting a lot of views, I'd like to add that this is how I am currently handling multiple errors with Joi. I'm just stringing together all my validation/sanitization functions and then rather than using a switch statement, all of my custom messages go in at the end in .messages({}). The same works with yup if you're using that on the frontend. This makes it much cleaner and more concise than a switch statement and an error message helper function.

```
const string = Joi.string();
const passPattern =
  "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*\\W)[a-zA-Z0-9\\S]{8,}$";

export const signupLocalSchema = Joi.object({
  email: string.email().trim().lowercase().required().messages({
    "string.email": "Not a valid email address.",
    "string.empty": "Email is required.",
  }),
  username: string.min(3).max(30).trim().lowercase().required().messages({
    "string.min": "Username must be between 3 and 30 characters.",
    "string.max": "Username must be between 3 and 30 characters.",
    "string.empty": "Username is required.",
  }),
  password: string.pattern(new RegExp(passPattern)).messages({
    "string.pattern.base":
      "Password must be at least 8 characters and contain at least 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase, 1 number and 1 special character.",
  }),
  confirmPassword: Joi.valid(Joi.ref("password")).messages({
    "any.only": "Passwords must match.",
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 6):

### Errors

I debugged your code and simply returning `() => 'some error message'` does not work for your solution. We need to return a function. You got an error because your `path` property on the custom error message was `undefined`.

[image]

#### Error Chaining does not work

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  prop: Joi.string()
           .min(9)
           .error(() => 'min error message')
           .required()
           .error(() => 'required error message');
});
```

#### Only one switched Error Message works

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string()
            .min(9)
            .required()
            .error((errors) => {
              for (err of errors) {
                switch (err.code) {
                  case ('string.min'): {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("prop min error message", ["prop"])(); // invoke
                  }
                  case 'any.required': {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("prop is required", ["prop"])(); // invoke
                  }
                  default: {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("prop has error", ["prop"])(); // invoke
                  }
                }
              }
            }),
});
```

#### Helper Function

The heart of my solution is the following function. It returns a `function` which returns an  custom error `object`.:

```
function simpleErrorMsgFunc(message, path) {
  return () => {
    return {
      toString: () => message,
      message,
      path,
    }
  };
}
```

#### Whole Solution

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

function simpleErrorMsgFunc(message, path) {
  return () => {
    return {
      toString: () => message,
      message,
      path,
    }
  };
}

const localRegistrationSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  // email is simple, we only need 1 error message
  email: Joi.string()
            .email()
            .required()
            .error(simpleErrorMsgFunc("Email is required", ["email"])),

  // username is advanced, we need 2 error message
  username: Joi.string()
            .min(3)
            .max(30)
            .required()
            .error((errors) => {
              for (err of errors) {
                switch (err.code) {
                  case ('string.min' || 'string.max'): {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("username must be between 3 and 30 characters", ["username"])(); // invoke
                  }
                  case 'any.required': {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("username is required", ["username"])(); // invoke
                  }
                  default: {
                    return simpleErrorMsgFunc("username has error", ["username"])(); // invoke
                  }
                }
              }
            }),

// password is advanced, we need 2 error message
  password: Joi.string()
               .min(6)
               .required()
               .error((errors) => {
                for (err of errors) {
                  switch (err.code) {
                    case ('string.min'): {
                      return simpleErrorMsgFunc("Password must be at least 6 characters", ["password"])(); // invoke
                    }
                    case 'any.required': {
                      return simpleErrorMsgFunc("Password is required", ["password"])(); // invoke
                    }
                    default: {
                      return simpleErrorMsgFunc("password has error", ["password"])(); // invoke
                    }
                  }
                }
              }),

  confirmPassword: Joi.valid(Joi.ref("password"))
                     .error(simpleErrorMsgFunc("Passwords must match", ['confirmPassword']))
});

const req = {
  body: {
    email: 'some@gmail.com',
    username: 'hee',
     password: '45645656',
     confirmPassword: '45645656_',
  },
};

const { error } = localRegistrationSchema.validate(req.body, {
  abortEarly: false
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
```

> P.S. I noticed that your `confirmPassword` property is not required!

Comment: Thank you! The solution works, but this can't be a rare use case. And if this is the best solution for checking for multiple errors, I fail to see why joi is so popular. I revised your solution in an attempt to make it cleaner and more modular by removing the switch statements and just having the same path checked multiple times (i.e. have multiple of the same key) each on a different schema. It results in much cleaner more modular code, but it only ends up checking the last instance of each key. If you know of any other solutions or libraries that can handle this use case better, let me know!

Comment: No problem Joel Jacobsen :) I also thought that there should be an easier solution in `joi` for multiple custom error messages. Unfortunately I didn't found something. I let you know if I find another validation library that works better for you needs.

Comment: Okay, I think the issue is that I was trying to use server-side validation to return user friendly messages to the client, when I would be better off using client-side validation for the user to see and just having server side validation for safety/edge cases and therefor not need to worry about custom messages (although it would still be nice if that were a bit easier).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
email: emailSchema.required().error(() => {
    return {
      message: "Email is required."
    };
}),
```

Comment: try using a custom label like `email: emailSchema.required().label('user email')

Comment: Already tried that as well, but it just changes what the path name is called in the standard error message; it doesn't actually change the whole error message.